# How do you manage foreign key relation in Microservice architecture?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I appreciate a straight forward answer.

Scenario 1: I need to display product information.

Product Service (PS) : Holds information about products
Pricing Service (XS) : Holds pricing information of each product
Aggregator service (AS) : Combines both product info and price.

Question: 'AS' make a call to 'PS'(With product ID) to get product info. Now, how does 'AS' fetch that specific product price, from the 'XS'?

The confusion here is, does PS Table have a DB column with ID to corresponding price in XS Table? Can we call it a foreign key? If so, does it introduce tight coupling between two services? Which is against principles of micro services.

Answer (score 1):

Well you may call that field as a "foreign key" but as long as you don't enforce any constraint on it then it should be fine.

From my view it is just a reference. It doesn't bring any tight coupling it provides some binding. Which is totally fine as far as microservices architecture concerned. If you think about a little bit broader in terms of possible implementation you may see that for example you can use a totally different database like relational one for pricing service and maybe
a document database for product service. And in that case it would be more clear that what you called as "foreign key" is just the reference for the actual record.

Having said that I may still question your solution like

- Why do you need a separate Aggregator service instead of directly using Product service?
- And same way why do you want to have a separate Pricing Service
- Would it be better if you keep the reference to product on pricing service than keeping the reference to price on product service?

But anyway foreign key part is just fine from my point of view.

Comment: 1) I need aggregator service as I need to make calls to multiple  Microservices and aggregate the results (I did not mention them in question, to keep it simple). For example, I also need product rating form rating service. Product quantity from inventory service, etc.

2) Separate pricing service as price is dependent on lot of factors, like inventory availability, demand, exchange value, discounts, etc.

3) Would love to understand why is it better to keep product reference in pricing service?

Comment: 1- Well there could still be many other reasons I can't see now for aggregate service justification but I still think your product service can do the aggregation. 3- Based on what I see in the context you have several aspects for a product. Like price, rating etc. It sounds to me like you have product as the central entity. That is why I thought it would be better to have a reference to product in the other services. and it was actually a wrongly written question. I change my original post.

Comment: 1) Agree, we don't need aggregator service 3) You may be right. But, I am still questioning issue we might face, if we have multiple reference in same table, than the other way

Comment: "multiple reference in same table" that is something you can manage on the price service side. Actually having multiple reference could even be fine depending on the requirements. Maybe you would like to keep history of price changes over time. So that should be a concern of pricing service to tackle this with maybe some field to keep state of activeness or having a constraint on the reference table to prevent having more than one reference etc. .